# How to format URL in _redirect call

Tags: zend-framework

My project folder is demo, inside which I have the folders application, library and public. My index.php is in public folder. So, I point my browser to localhost/demo/public. Inside my application folder, i have a controllers folder, inside which I have my IndexController. In this index controller, my indexAction method is :

```
   $this->_redirect('/auth/login');
   $this->_helper->layout->disableLayout();
   $this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender(true);
```

So, in this method, I want to redirect to AuthController which is in the same controllers diretory, to its action login. But the browser renders :

The requested URL /demo/public/auth/login was not found on this server.

AuthController is in controllers, not in public folder. How do I correctly format the URL string in my _redirect call?

Answer (score 0):

Use Redirector action helper

```
$this->_helper->redirector('auth','login');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the url view helper, for example like so:

```
$this->_redirect($this->view->url(array('controller'=>'auth','action'=>'login');
```

Another option would be trying to format your URL absolutely, such as:

```
$this->_redirect($_SERVER['HTTP_ROOT'].'/auth/login')
```

Though the first option should be safer.